# Case Expression filter issue for SSRS

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a query that I want to use in a SSRS filter and it's not working.

Here is the query:

```
 SELECT
     empid, empName, 
     CASE 
         WHEN HM.Pos = 1 THEN 'MANAGER'
         WHEN HM.Pos = 2 THEN 'HR MANAGER'
         WHEN HM.Pos = 3 THEN 'AC MANAGER'
         ELSE 'IT Manager' 
    END [Position]
FROM
    dbo.tbl_Emp  e
LEFT JOIN  
    dbo.pos pos ON e.id = pos.id
LEFT JOIN  
    dbo.HM HM ON e.id = HM.id
WHERE
    [Position] = 'HR MANAGER'
```

Column `Position` in `WHERE` clause is not recognized. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: you can't use aliases in a query, make a cte or a subselect and filter then

Answer (score 2):

Your query can be significantly simplified here to the following:

```
SELECT e.empid, --Assumed qualifier
       e.empName, --Assumed qualifier
       'HR MANAGER' AS Position
FROM dbo.tbl_Emp e
     JOIN dbo.HM ON e.id=HM.id
WHERE HM.Pos = 2;
```

Firstly, I removed the `CASE` expression, as it'll only ever resolve to `'HR MANAGER'`; so might as well just write `'HR MANAGER'`.

I also remove the `LEFT JOIN` to `dbo.pos` as I can't see that it's used, and therefore it does nothing (apart from possibly causing duplicate rows, which I doubt is desired). Note that I do *assume* that the first 2 columns are from `dbo.tbl_Emp`, so if this assumption is wrong, you may need to address this.

Next I change your `LEFT JOIN` to `dbo.HM` to an `INNER JOIN`, and remove the alias. The alias was pointless as you alias `HM` to `HM`; it did nothing. The `INNER JOIN` because you require that `HM.Pos` have a non-`NULL` value in the `WHERE`. It's *impossible* for `HM.Pos` to have a non-`NULL` value if no row was found. As such it should be an `INNER JOIN`.

Then, finally, I change the `WHERE` to reference the column in the table `HM`, not an expression defined in the `SELECT`, which can't be referenced at that point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you wan to pass, in this case, "HR Manager" to the dataset query from a parameter. If that is true then you need to setup your parameter to match your HM table.

Ultimately, your parameter **values** would be 1,2,3,4 and respective labels would be "Manager", "HR Manager", "AC Manager", "ITManager". The user  would see the text(label) but you pass the value to the query.

You will need to change the WHERE clause to somethingg like

```
WHERE HM.Pos = @myParamName
```